# Bash multiple copy latest files with timestamp using regex

Tags: regex, bash, copy, rename, cp

please, I need a help with rename of multiple files. One application in our generating everyday 3 reports with filemask `OPEN_REPORTn_yyyymmddHH24Miss.csv`, e.g listing like this one:

```
/mnt/server/OPEN_REPORT1_20180604130922.csv
/mnt/server/OPEN_REPORT2_20180604130922.csv
/mnt/server/OPEN_REPORT3_20180604130922.csv
```

I want this files copy as

```
/mnt/server/OPEN_REPORT1.csv
/mnt/server/OPEN_REPORT2.csv
/mnt/server/OPEN_REPORT3.csv
```

and keep original files without change the name (so, that means that I must list only 3 last files)

I have this solution:

```
cp $(ls -t /mnt/server/OPEN_REPORT1_* | head -n1) /mnt/server/OPEN_REPORT1.csv
cp $(ls -t /mnt/server/OPEN_REPORT2_* | head -n1) /mnt/server/OPEN_REPORT2.csv
cp $(ls -t /mnt/server/OPEN_REPORT3_* | head -n1) /mnt/server/OPEN_REPORT3.csv
```

But this solution is not too effective because I'm using more `cp` command as I need. I want copy those files with only one use `cp` command and with regular expressions.

I'm trying solution like this one:

```
for file in $(ls -t /mnt/server/OPEN_REPORT?_??????????????.csv | head -n3); do echo ${file} | sed 's/OPEN_REPORT([0-9]{1})/$1/'; done
```

but result for echo doesn't looks fine.

Please any help with solution? Thanks for any advice

**SOLUTION** (thanks to [David Peltier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7990577/david-peltier)):

```
for file in $(ls -t /mnt/server/OPEN_REPORT?_??????????????.csv | head -n3); do cp $file ${file%_*}.csv; done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
for file in $(ls -1 /mnt/server/*.csv); do cp /mnt/server/$file /mnt/server/${file%_*}.csv;done
```

Bash can do replacement and you no longer need to use sed.

${var%Pattern}, ${var%%Pattern}

```
${var%Pattern} Remove from $var the shortest part of $Pattern that matches the back end of $var.

${var%%Pattern} Remove from $var the longest part of $Pattern that matches the back end of $var.
```

https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Comment: `$(ls -1 /mnt/server/*.csv)` should just be `/mnt/server/*.csv`. `ls` does nothing useful here.

Comment: Thanks @TomFenech, didn't know that was possible..thanks but there is one inconvenient, it does print something even if it do not find anything

Comment: Also you should quote your variable expansions, otherwise any spaces or other awkward characters in `$file` will cause the `cp` command to fail.

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly: `for file in $(ls -t /mnt/server/OPEN_REPORT?_??????????????.csv | head -n3); do cp $file ${file%_*}.csv; done`